# ¿Cómo obtener el id de un botón en PHP?

Tags: php, html

mi problema es como puedo obtener el id de un botón en php, si es con el value si se cogerlo, pero con el id no. Lo que estoy haciendo es una página web de videoclub de películas y Tengo un botón Ver:

pero cuando quiero obtener el id, porque si se lo pongo en value se cambia el texto del botón. De que forma puedo hacerlo?
prueba.php

```
// PARA RECOGER LOS DATOS DE LA BASE DE DATOS
    public function mostrar() {
        include './conexion.php';
        $consulta = "SELECT Ruta_Imagen, Nombre FROM pelicula;";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) <= 1) {
            echo "No hay últimas películas registradas.";
        } else {
            while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
                // MOSTRAMOS LAS PELICULAS
                echo "<table class='elementoPelicula' width='15%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' title='".$fila['Nombre']."'>";
                // MOSTRAMOS LA IMAGEN
                echo "<tr><td><img src='".$fila['Ruta_Imagen']."'></td></tr>";
                // MOSTRAMOS EL NOMBRE
                echo "<tr><td>".$fila['Nombre']."</td></tr>";
                // MOSTRAMOS LOS BOTONES
                echo "<tr><td><input type='submit' name='nombrePelicula' id='".$fila['Nombre']."' class='verPelicula' value='Ver'></td></tr>";
                echo "<tr><td><input type='submit' class='anadirCesta' value='Añadir a la cesta.'></td></tr>";
                echo "</table>";
            }
        }
    }
```

Ahora lo que no sé realizar es como poder obtener el ID del botón VER, ya que dicho botón tendrá un id diferente según el nombre de la pelicula.

Comment: Hola por favor, puedes incluir el código que tienes desarrollado es que así tienes la pregunta muy amplia. Gracias

Comment: Ya, eso es la prueba que estoy haciendo, lo que quiero que en prueba2.php en vez de $_POST['opcion]' quiero coger el valor que tiene asignado id="".

Comment: Yo te recomendaria que usaras mejor una etiqueta `<button type="submit"></button>` y no un `<input type="submit">` y con eso solucionarias tu problema

Comment: Muchas Gracias Daniel Mauricio, ahora si podré seguir. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes directamente. El ID pertenece al DOM de tu página, sirve al HTML y al javascript. 
Si quieres pasarlo al PHP tendrás que crear una función javascript que simula el submit y envia los datos por ajax al servidor y esta función tiene que leer los IDs y pasarlos al ajax como parámetros extras

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias a todos por vuestra respuesta. Soy nuevo en PHP, pero muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

antes que nada te recomiendo poner codigo del problema para tener mas claro el problema, se me ocurre esto: `value="(valor)"` solo asigna el texto que el botón tendrá en cuestión, si estas trabajando con javascript puedes asignar un `id="(valor)"`  y mediante un evento `onclick` hacer un `script` que tome el evento

```
function confirmar()
            {
                 var email = $('#email').val();
                 <lo que vayas a hacer>
            }



    <input id="loggg" onclick="confirmar()" type="button" value="Iniciar">
```

Tambien puede simplemente tomar el valor sin scripts

```
    <form   action="logg.php" method="POST"> 

                <INPUT type="text" Required name="codigo" placeholder="CUM...">
                <br><br>
                <INPUT type="text" Required name="nombre" placeholder="Contraseña...">
                <br><br>
                <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Agregar">

    </form>
```

ya y en el otro documento

```
    <?php

            $Cum= $_POST['codigo'];
            $Contraseña= $_POST['nombre'];
    ?>
```